# Making a complex MySQL View editable

Tags: c#, mysql, xaml

I have created a XAML view, that has several text boxes bound to a table.  However, I now need to change this binding to a rather (over) complex query that has been created by the client.

Will I still be able to edit the data (behind the view), as I am seeing a warning that the MySQL views don't have a primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you can't update a View without the PK. Infact **all** view fields must correspond **1:1** (order, type..) to the table fields. There are other rules and you can find them in the [MySql Specs of Updatable and Insertable Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html).

Note e.g. that the complex view can't have aggreagate functions or a union clause etc etc..

Maybe you can create code to bring the updates back via your original view but to do so you would have to find a reliable mapping between the views..

Can you identify the way in which the rules are broken by the client's view?

Comment: Unfortunately, there were several links to tables to produce the view.  I have now created a work around, which involved brining the key data into the main table.  I wouldn't normally do this, but it's a very small database that is being phased on in 12 months, and this change will have almost zero impact on the data/performance/relationships - so it seems like a good fit.  Thanks for the feedback/help.